# MySQL password security

Tags: mysql, vb.net, security, reverse-engineering

I want to build a VB.NET application that will connect to a MySQL database.
I was thinking of putting the MySQL password on the My.Setting file, but that's easy to read. Which would be the safest way to put the password on the program?
I don't want to ask for it on start-up, I want it to be embedded on the software, but WHERE?

Comment: There are passwords and there are passwords.  I would not give any user a password to the database - it can allow then to get at the DB without your app.  Instead, have users verify themselves to the app which then uses its own credentials.  Options depend on whether it is a desktop or web app and other details we have no inkling of.  Also, please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wellll.....  If it's stored in an automatically program-readable format (aka, the user doesn't have to enter any kind of password or credential to enable the application to make use of said database password), then there isn't exactly a "safe" way since any kind of meaningful encryption requires that the user enter some credential to retrieve the encrypted information. You could store it in a module as Base64 text for obfuscation, but that's not really "safe."  At all.  It's just encoded differently (NOT encrypted).

The bigger question to me is, is the *environment* safe? On the back end of a website for example, the password for sql databases is usually stored *in-the-clear* in the php config files... but that's because the *environment* is secure: php source cannot be obtained by the public, and trusted users with access to the backend are assumed to be non-malicious.

So, that raises some questions:

- Where is the application running from?
- Where is the MySQL Database, local or remote?
- How many people have access to this database or will be using this app?

These are all considerations that should be accounted for.

One other thing - if you're building a .NET application, there are certain .NET code-obfuscators out there that play with your compiled code to make it quite difficult to pillage once compiled.  This may be of interest to you.  I believe Dotfuscator ships standard with Visual Studio?  You can register for a free account with them.

Comment: I'm trying to build an RPG multiplayer game and the account/character information is stored on a MySQL database. The images, music, connection and everything but the account and character information is client based.

Currently I have the connection string, including ip, port, username and password on a module inside the project.

Comment: Judging from your explanation and my limited knowledge of web interfaces, I'd wager you really need to build your desktop app to utilize a secure tunnel to talk to a _web app/service_; let the web app/service do the database talking, since it lives next door; then have the service relay messages back via the secure tunnel.  That way, your database username/password are NOT being sent over the wire (they should never be).  The desktop app should only send the player's credentials to a remote server that validates and handles all database related stuff internally, and sends the results back.

Comment: You could write a simple php script that could handle this, even, and I believe visual studio has support for async web service calls. I think. Don't quote me.